# odds ratio calculation issue in R

Tags: r

This is my experimental design which im trying to use taken from this [paper](https://github.com/gerstung-lab/MDS-expression/blob/master/Supplementary-Data-2-MDS.R) code which Im trying to implement it for my dataset which I would like to use.

The code which Im using is here

```
genomicData = tcgaDesign[,colnames(tcgaDesign)[2:27]]
interactions <- interactionsGenes <- sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(i) sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(j) {f<- try(fisher.test(genomicData[,i], genomicData[,j]), silent=TRUE); if(class(f)=="try-error") 0 else ifelse(f$estimate>1, -log10(f$p.val),log10(f$p.val))} ))
oddsRatio <- oddsGenes <- sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(i) sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(j) {f<- try(fisher.test(genomicData[,i] + .5, genomicData[,j] +.5), silent=TRUE); if(class(f)=="try-error") f=NA else f$estimate} ))
w <- p.adjust(tcgaGlm$F.p.value,"BH")<0.05
oddsExpression <- sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(i) sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(j) {f<- try(fisher.test(abs(testResults[w,i]), abs(testResults[w,j])), silent=TRUE); if(class(f)=="try-error") f=NA else f$estimate} ))
interactionsExpression <- sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(i) sapply(1:ncol(genomicData), function(j) {f<- try(fisher.test(abs(testResults[w,i]), abs(testResults[w,j])), silent=TRUE); if(class(f)=="try-error") 0 else ifelse(f$estimate>1, -log10(f$p.val),log10(f$p.val))} ))
oddsRatio[lower.tri(oddsRatio)] <- oddsExpression[lower.tri(oddsExpression)]
interactions[lower.tri(interactions)] <- interactionsExpression[lower.tri(interactions)]
```

Till that point all fine

Then the next step is adding NA to diagonal

```
diag(interactions) <- NA
diag(oddsRatio) <- NA
colnames(oddsRatio) <- rownames(oddsRatio) <- colnames(interactions) <- rownames(interactions) <- colnames(genomicData)
```

The problem occurs here

```
oddsRatio[10^-abs(interactions) > 0.05] = 1
oddsRatio[oddsRatio<1e-3] = 1e-4
oddsRatio[oddsRatio>1e3] = 1e4
logOdds=log10(oddsRatio)
```

When i run this

```
oddsRatio[10^-abs(interactions) > 0.05] = 1
```

> Error in abs(interactions) :
> non-numeric argument to mathematical function

What is going wrong here I would like to know im may be I'm not getting the code right?

My data used for this is here
data from [tcgaExpr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c6lFwH_5olDuvt6XVI5_PuWutaDOI5Id/view?usp=sharing)

```
    tcgaExpr <- read.table("data.txt",sep = "\t",strip.white = FALSE,check.names = FALSE,header=TRUE,row.names = 1)

tcgaGlm = lmFit(as.matrix(tcgaExpr), design = tcgaDesign) 
tcgaGlm = eBayes(tcgaGlm)
```

data

```
dput(tcgaDesign)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 
0, 0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 
0.136752136752137, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 
0, 0.136752136752137, 0, 0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0.136752136752137, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 
0.0769230769230769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 
0, 0.0769230769230769, 0, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0.128205128205128, 1, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.128205128205128, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 1, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0.128205128205128, 1, 
0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.128205128205128, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0508474576271186, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0508474576271186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0508474576271186, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0508474576271186, 
0.0508474576271186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0508474576271186, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0508474576271186, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.0508474576271186, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 1, 0, 
0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 
0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.0598290598290598, 
0, 0.0598290598290598, 1, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0598290598290598, 1, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0598290598290598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.0598290598290598, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 
0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 
0, 0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(126L, 27L), .Dimnames = list(c("TCGA-AB-2971", 
"TCGA-AB-2930", "TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2851", "TCGA-AB-3011", 
"TCGA-AB-2949", "TCGA-AB-2981", "TCGA-AB-2965", "TCGA-AB-2822", 
"TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2973", "TCGA-AB-2987", "TCGA-AB-2986", 
"TCGA-AB-2921", "TCGA-AB-2863", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-2812", 
"TCGA-AB-2940", "TCGA-AB-2996", "TCGA-AB-2983", "TCGA-AB-2859", 
"TCGA-AB-2913", "TCGA-AB-2917", "TCGA-AB-2929", "TCGA-AB-2825", 
"TCGA-AB-2900", "TCGA-AB-2846", "TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-2871", 
"TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2901", "TCGA-AB-2920", "TCGA-AB-2966", 
"TCGA-AB-2814", "TCGA-AB-2942", "TCGA-AB-2870", "TCGA-AB-2847", 
"TCGA-AB-2844", "TCGA-AB-2806", "TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2861", 
"TCGA-AB-2916", "TCGA-AB-2878", "TCGA-AB-2817", "TCGA-AB-2830", 
"TCGA-AB-2892", "TCGA-AB-2858", "TCGA-AB-2877", "TCGA-AB-2939", 
"TCGA-AB-2890", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2918", "TCGA-AB-2898", 
"TCGA-AB-2908", "TCGA-AB-2866", "TCGA-AB-2910", "TCGA-AB-2915", 
"TCGA-AB-2977", "TCGA-AB-2912", "TCGA-AB-2943", "TCGA-AB-2881", 
"TCGA-AB-2988", "TCGA-AB-3000", "TCGA-AB-2948", "TCGA-AB-2895", 
"TCGA-AB-2931", "TCGA-AB-2936", "TCGA-AB-2934", "TCGA-AB-2914", 
"TCGA-AB-2992", "TCGA-AB-2869", "TCGA-AB-2963", "TCGA-AB-2928", 
"TCGA-AB-2924", "TCGA-AB-2818", "TCGA-AB-2975", "TCGA-AB-2874", 
"TCGA-AB-2979", "TCGA-AB-2826", "TCGA-AB-2990", "TCGA-AB-2885", 
"TCGA-AB-2835", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2955", "TCGA-AB-2845", 
"TCGA-AB-2836", "TCGA-AB-2925", "TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2820", 
"TCGA-AB-2899", "TCGA-AB-3008", "TCGA-AB-2994", "TCGA-AB-2853", 
"TCGA-AB-2896", "TCGA-AB-2867", "TCGA-AB-2999", "TCGA-AB-2888", 
"TCGA-AB-2839", "TCGA-AB-2865", "TCGA-AB-3007", "TCGA-AB-2932", 
"TCGA-AB-2976", "TCGA-AB-2834", "TCGA-AB-2840", "TCGA-AB-2880", 
"TCGA-AB-2998", "TCGA-AB-2813", "TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2950", 
"TCGA-AB-2810", "TCGA-AB-2935", "TCGA-AB-2821", "TCGA-AB-2952", 
"TCGA-AB-2886", "TCGA-AB-2805", "TCGA-AB-2876", "TCGA-AB-2808", 
"TCGA-AB-2937", "TCGA-AB-2927", "TCGA-AB-2883", "TCGA-AB-2919", 
"TCGA-AB-3012", "TCGA-AB-2875", "TCGA-AB-2984", "TCGA-AB-2970", 
"TCGA-AB-2933"), c("Offset", "CEBPA", "DNMT3A", "FLT3_ITD", "FLT3_TKD", 
"IDH1", "IDH2", "KIT", "KRAS", "NPM1", "NRAS", "PTPN11", "RUNX1", 
"SMC1A", "SMC3", "TET2", "TP53", "U2AF1", "WT1", "complex", "minus5_5q", 
"minus7q", "plus8_8q", "plus21", "t_15_17", "t_8_21", "inv16_t16_16"
)))
```

Comment: Your code refers to `tcgaGlm` but you have not included it as data, or derived it in code, so your code is not reproducible.

Comment: yes i got it sorry I will add that to it  @SamR I have added my test data to the question thank your for your response

Comment: I do not see where `tcgaExpr` is used in your code and we still do not have `tcgaGlm`

Comment: @Basti updated it i missed it while copy pasting

Comment: I am limited in statistics but you seem to have non integer values for colnames(tcgaDesign)[20:27] so your table is not a contingency table and you cannot apply a fisher test

Comment: yes i think that is the issue once I removed those column now it works ...I think those gives null values